# Usage of Sparse matrix in neural nets

Tags: python, neural-network, sparse-matrix

I have started doing a project named Talking Data User Demographics. In this project i need to find the gender and age group of a person whose phone data is provided to me. In the datset given to me  i could find only phone model and phone brand for almost 70% of the data and remaining 30% has events,event labels, location,many other features includeing model and brand. So, i thought of building a model seperately for devices with events and devices without evnts. As a part of finding correct model i have used various algorithms. When i tried neural nets i have got less log loss for devices with out events so, i thought of trying the same for devices with events also but it is giving the error "sparse matrices are not supported." But if it is so it is runnning fine when i have the model for devices with out events. Below i have attached a snippet as a proof of what i have told, please help me in understanding this any suggestion would be appreciated.

The file attached contain a code which runs the code perfectly even when sparse matrices are used in model.fit(). [1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I99t.png)

Now in the below attached file it is giving the error when sparse matrix are passed to model.fit()[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1b9f.png)

please gothrough the entire code for best reference.[code snippet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hR5yLt8nLyde8CVbKBLBy35ghLJ_7Lxt)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1b9f.png)

Comment: Please directly insert your code snippet, so your question can be later better found by someone having the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have added the code snippet please go through this and help me if you are aware of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: Do not use a sparse matrix in a neural network as such, as it will provide bad results. Just transform your sparse matrix using PCA before running NN. You have for example PCA in scikit-learn with the option whitening which can be useful also for the gradient descent.

In your example you want to compare two models run with two different datasets. Two different models and two different data sets may provide completely different results. It makes no sense to compare them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have understood what you have told me, But i have a doubt that why it is giving me an error when sparse matrices are used in NN while it hasn't given the error when used  the above sparse matrix i.e you can see in the code snippet that it worked fine for 1st model and it's giving error for second model , I want to know what's the difference between them if possible how can i correct it.

Comment: Which page of your snippet  exactly? Your code is huge.

Comment: NN model in 36th page is running perfectly even with sparse matrices and NN model at 38th page is raising the error.

Comment: In the two files you have two different training sets and two different models in each. That is difficult to compare.Try applying the same model once to a dataset and secondly on the other dataset and see the result.

Comment: Though the two models are different and training sets are different the error it is giving is it can't handle sparse matrix right if it is so how the 1st model has handeled the sparse matrix??

Comment: The error states that SparseTensor cannot be converted to Tensor. Your snippet is an image, so you are the only one who has access to the code. Just check which line of your code provides the error and tel us.

Comment: Hi mam i am sorry for not providing you the code earlier,here is the link for the code          https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Kjkv_JqgmDJoQNfz1kouWXQgDbhaN8IY

Comment: Please click on the link code will open if not in the page opened you will find the dowload option please download it and then you can use google colab to open. please help me in understaning the error.

Comment: OK. Please tell me what did you try in order to find the line which gives the error? Did you have difficulties in finding that line, and if it is the case, which were they?

Comment: No, it is cleaarly stating the error line that SparseTensor cannot be converted to Tensor i.e from that i have understood that usage of sparse matrix in model.fit() is causing that error so i haveconverted that entire sparse to dense and executed model has run without giving any error but i could find that the logloss that i have obtained is more. So, i thought it would give less log loss if my model runs on sparse matrix so i want to know why only this mmodel is giving error when sprase is passes while the previous worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I have done my model 1 with both sparse and dense and checked the logloss values sparse matrix has given the best so, I think even in the second model that would be the case and so trying that with sparse which is giving the error

Comment: Well, two different models and two different data sets may provide completely different results. It makes no sense to compare them, moreover without having acess to the data.

Comment: I have sent the link of code through which you can acces it. please check this link drive.google.com/open?id=1Kjkv_JqgmDJoQNfz1kouWXQgDbhaN8IY